# Brocha for hearing great Chazan or concert

Tags: halacha-theory

Why is there no Birchas HaNehenin for hearing a great Chazan or concert? Prior posts on topic attempting to answer by distinguishing things that enter the body. However, we do have Brochos for special sights, and seeing them does not enter the body any more so than hearing music. We have such Brochos for enjoyable sights, tastes and smells, several Brochos for different besamin, but nothing to thank HaShem for our hearing pleasurable music? This idea came to me on Rosh Hashanah when I observed a blind young man so obviously enjoying the Chazan and everyone’s back up harmony.

Comment: There's a blessing for hearing thunder. (Is there another natural unusual sound phenomenon?)

Comment: This is still the same question. If you want to ask on the sources quoted there, then I would vote to reopen, but as it stands, this is still asking the same thing, just that you don’t like the answers there.

Comment: None if the prior posts address the fact that we do make Brochos on seeing special sights, so the distinction of it not entering the body does not apply. We make Brochos on enjoyable tastes, smells and sights, but not on hearing enjoyable music or singing. This thought came to me on Rosh Hashanah when I observed a blind young man so obviously enjoying the Chazzan and everyone’s back up harmony.

Comment: @dan Yez's answer addresses this. Specifically, the Maggid Ta'alumah that he quotes actually explicitly mentions music (though to be fair, Yez didn't mention that part).

Comment: @Alex . Is there a way that you could attach, quote or link me to that Maggid Ta'alumah that mentions/discusses music?

Comment: @dan על כלם אם אמר שהכל נהיה יצא. פי' הרמב"ם אפילו על פת ויין בא לדייק לשון על כולם ולי הקטן נראה דבדיעבד יוצא בברכת שהכל על כל ענינים שבעולם דהיינו על ברכת הריח וכיוצא דזיל בתר טעמא ונ"ל לפ"ז דעל כל הנאות עוה"ז שלא תיקנו חז"ל ברכה כגון שמיעת כלי שיר והנאת תשמיש יש לחייב את עצמו בברכת שהכל ויברך ויכלול בברכתו גם על הנאה הזאת ולא יהנה מן העוה"ז בלא ברכה ולא ימעול

Answer (score 1):

I dont have a source, but I remember once hearing that the reason we don't make a Bracha on hearing, not even in the Birchas HaShachar like we make on seeing, is because it is continuous, there is never a time when one does not hear. Even while alseep, we hear (as in you hear your alarm clock).

Comment: Interesting answer. Perhaps, this should be modified for those who wear cochlear implants. Maybe they **should** be saying a bracha.

Comment: What about the blessing before **hearing** the Megillah, or the blessing before **hearing** the shofar? What about the blessing upon **hearing** thunder? Clearly, we do recite blessings over things we can only hear.

Comment: @ezra Thunder is a good point, although Shofar and Megilla one is Yotzei with Shomea K'Oneh.

Comment: None if the prior posts address the fact that we do make Brochos on seeing special sights, so the distinction of it not entering the body does not apply. We make Brochos on enjoyable tastes, smells and sights, but not on hearing enjoyable music or singing. This thought came to me on Rosh Hashanah when I observed a blind young man so obviously enjoying the Chazzan and everyone’s back up harmony.

Comment: @arecaps Shofar isn't Shomea Keoneh. It's not considered as if I yelled the Tekia sound. That's not even a Mitzva. The Mitzva is to hear not to blow