# Why don't we make a bracha on the sense of hearing?

Tags: blessing

Why don't we make a bracha on the sense of hearing, like we make on seeing פוקח עורים ?

Comment: We do אשר נתן לשכוי בינה

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95381/759

Comment: @DoubleAA - That question is about a bracha on a special sound, this one is about the general sense of hearing.

Comment: @DoubleAA - However the one answer there does address this.

Comment: Why ask about hearing? Isn’t sight unique in having a beracha? What Beracha do you make on the ability to smell, taste, or feel?

Comment: @DonielF - Good point, but a person interaction with others is affected much more with his sense of hearing.

Answer (score -3):

What Double might hint on [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95384/15579) is that acc. to Rambam [Teffila 7,8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Prayer_and_the_Priestly_Blessing.7.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> ?וְכָל בְּרָכָה מֵהֶן שֶׁלֹּא נִתְחַיֵּב בָּהּ אֵינוֹ מְבָרֵךְ אוֹתָהּ:  - כֵּיצַד
>   לָן בִּכְסוּתוֹ אֵינוֹ מְבָרֵךְ כְּשֶׁעוֹמֵד מַלְבִּישׁ עֲרוּמִים."
>
> Any of the above blessings for which there is no occasion, [*the obligation is not renewed - נתחייב, my translation*] is not recited. For example: If one passed the night without removing his clothes, on arising in the morning he does not recite the blessing, "Who clothes the naked".

Therefore, if we assume that we hear all the time even when asleep, we don't feel the moment of enjoying this sense and therefore we don't say a blessing.

---

However, since we use to recite all blessings together at a shul, regardlessly of previous experiences, (as we Pasken that a blind person does say the Brocho on seeing), it seems that the reason is invalidated. But as we can't add Brochos of our own, we're, IMHO, stuck without this Brocho.

Comment: What about taste? Also, you bring a proof from the Rambam and reject said proof from the Rema? Sefardim still follow the Mechaber, who follows the Rambam, to say the berachos on those events instead of in shul.

Comment: @DonielF I don't understand your comment. I clarified Double's link to the other answer, that acc. to Rambam if one enjoys something all the time he can't say a Brocho. So Sefardim should not say Brocho on hearing. What proof of Remo? I mentioned that in the second part?

Comment: Let me try to rephrase my comment, as it was two separate questions: 1. You don’t taste in your sleep, so why don’t we make a Beracha on the sense of taste upon awaking, the way we make a Beracha on the restoration of the sense of sight? 2. Your final paragraph, based on “since we use to recite all blessings together at a shul, regardlessly of previous experiences,” is the Rema’s opinion - only Ashkenazim follow this. You can’t disprove the Rambam based on something he doesn’t hold of.

Comment: @DonielF I think the line was misleading, it wasn't a part of the answer, just a note. I said exactly the opposite, that since Remo made all Brochos be said in shul, I'd *expect* to establish a Brocho on hearing, since the original Rambam's explanation won't work.